# Regex to Extract First Part of URL

Tags: java, regex

I need a java regex to extract parts of a URL.

For example, take the following URLs:

```
http://localhost:81/example
https://test.com/test
http://test.com/
```

I would want my regex expression to return:

```
http://localhost:81
https://test.com
http://test.com
```

I will be using this in a Java patcher.

This is what I have so far, problem is it takes the whole URLs:

```
^https?:\/\/(?!.*:\/\/)\S+
```

Comment: I wouldn't use a regex for this... I would just look for the first `/` after the first `://` using basic String functions (assuming you know all your URLs will contain a `://`)...

Comment: I won't be using a Java program for this. I will need to provide a regex expression to a program that will use the expression.

Comment: Maybe give http://www.regular-expressions.info/ a look? This is a pretty simple regex problem and that can help you get started.

Comment: this is what I have so far ^https?:\/\/(?!.*:\/\/)\S+ the problem is it takes in the end too after the port

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Building off your attempt, try this:

```
^https?://[^/]+
```

I'm assuming that you want to capture everything until the first / after http://? (That's what I was getting from your examples - if not, please post some more).

Are these URLs given as one input, or are each a different string?

**Edit:** It was pointed out that there were unnecessary escapes, so fixed to a more condensed version

Comment: +1 but there is no need to escape `/` in regex since it is not meta-character. This version `^https?://[^/]` should do the trick (based on OP examples).

Comment: @Pshemo - thanks. I probably should have caught that, but I just wanted to build on what the OP came up with. Updated.

Comment: @CorrugatedAir update seems very similar to #OscarMederos answer

Comment: @TomSarduy It's the same answer I posted originally, minus the extra escape characters that were pointed out in the comments above

Answer (score 6):

```
import Java.net.URL

//snip

URL url = new URL(urlString);
return url.getProtocol() + "://" + url.getAuthority();
```

The right tool for the right job.

Comment: nice, that's much better than a regex approach.

Comment: I won't be using a Java program for this. I will need to provide a regex expression to a program that will use the expression.

Comment: @user2019260 hmm .. `(.*://.*?)(?:/|$)`

Comment: This is what I have so far ^https?:\/\/(?!.*:\/\/)\S+ problem is it takes in the end of the URL too after the port

Answer (score 1):

Language independent answer:

For the whitespace: replace `/^\s+/` with the empty string.

For removing the path information from the URL, if you can assume there aren't any slashes in the path (i.e. you're not dealing with `http://localhost:81/foo/bar/baz`), replace `/\/[^\/]+$/` with the empty string. If there might be more slashes, you might try something like replacing `/(^\s*.*:\/\/[^\/]+)\/.*/` with `$1`.

Answer (score 1):

A simple one: `^(https?://[^/]+)`